# Disable custom dates in date range picker from code behind in ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, date, date-range

I Have code like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var some_date_range = ['20-10-2017','24-10-2017','27-10-2017','28-10-2017','25-10-2017'];

$('#daterange').daterangepicker({
    isInvalidDate: function (date) {
      for (var ii = 0; ii < some_date_range.length; ii++) {
       if (date.format('DD-MM-YYYY') == some_date_range[ii]) {
         return true;
       }
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

I want block custom date in date range picker, and usually i put variable into javascript and code worked, how if i set variable date from code behind using textbox or label in ASP.Net .

please your advice

Answer (score 0):

```
This code will disable custom dates in date range picker.

var naArray = ["20170822", "20170823", "20170824", "20170825"];
  function isDateAvailable(date){
    return naArray.indexOf(date.format('YYYYMMDD')) > -1;
  }

 $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
  isInvalidDate: isDateAvailable
 });
```

Comment: Please update your answer to explain what your code is doing.

Comment: that code same function like me, how if set array javascript from code behind in asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

Okay... it's not entirely clear what you want here, but it sounds like you just want to know how to set the javascript array variable with ASP, in which case you would simply write:

```
var some_date_range = [<%= name_of_your_array_variable_from_asp %>];
```